# Installing Oracle DataModeler assistance

Tags: database, oracle, data-modeling

I would like to download and install the Oracle DataModeler
But im stuck at the window that says:
"please specify the path to the java jdk home:_________" 
What do i do?

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What operating system are you using / version of Java do you have installed. If you are on Windows, are you environment variables setup correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You tell it where Java is installed. SQL Developer Data Modeler is a java application and can't run without Java.

If you're on Windows, you can download the package that includes the JDK. If you're not on Windows, install Java 8 (JDK), and then run SQL Developer. If it doesn't see Java, it will ask for the path. Give it the path from your install.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Datamodeler, the first time I launched the software it asked me for a java path. On my machine this was /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.  If you are running on a linux distro, there should be an opt subdirectory with a configuration file that you can edit manually:

/opt/datamodeler/datamodeler/bin/datamodeler.conf

try changing the last line of the file from
SetJavaHome ../../jdk

to 
SetJavaHome /path/to/your/java (whatever your java path is)

I'm still having issues -- but this might work for you.